# What does Rasmussen and Williams find "unexciting" about the Student's t-process?

Tags: gaussian-process, t-distribution

Section 9.9 of [Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/) (aka Rasmussen & Williams), "Student's *t* Process", contains the following exercise:

**Exercise** Consider the generating process implied by eq. (9.2), and write a program to draw functions at random. Characterize the difference between the Student's *t* process and the corresponding Gaussian process (obtained in the limit $\alpha \to \infty$), and explain why the *t* process is perhaps not as exciting as one might have hoped.

equation 9.2 is

$$
\begin{align}
\tilde{k}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x'}) = \tau^{-1}k(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x'}), \qquad
p(\tau|\alpha,\beta) = \frac{\alpha^\alpha}{\beta^{\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha)}\tau^{\alpha-1}
\exp\left(-\frac{\tau\alpha}{\beta}\right)
\end{align}
$$

"where *k* is any valid covariance function", and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the parameters of the t distribution.

As one without the skill or ambition to work the exercise, I'm still intrigued — what about the sampled functions are we expected to see, and find disappointing?

Comment: I'm not sure, but have a feeling it has to do with [the following paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229630925_The_emperor's_new_clothes_A_critique_of_the_multivariate_t_regression_model)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen thanks. In that case I guess the expected finding from the exercise is that you can't tell the difference between the two :)